# What's the best way to "convert" a PHP file to HTML?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

First of all, I know that you can't convert a PHP file to HTML due to PHPs nature. So what I rather want to do is have a script run through and scrape all the pages and save them down correspondingly (eg. `/help/how-to-stackoverflow` should become `/help/how-to-stackoverflow.html`).

The site I want to *convert* doesn't use dynamic server-side logic, meaning that no matter who you are, the same URL always gives you the same result and there's nothing going on behind the scenes. It also doesn't use parameters and such.

If possible, the process should be easy to integrate into automation (aka be a command to run), however, this is not a requirement.

So, what is the best way to do that without going through and exporting every page manually?

Comment: "Converting a PHP file to HTML" sounds fundamentally weird. What you are trying to achieve exactly? Displaying the source code of the PHP files in browser? Your question is not clear. "The site I want to convert.." do you mean scraping other web pages using PHP? Also, what did you try so far?

Comment: @edigu What I basically want to achieve is for a software to scrape an entire site that I made and save the pages it scraped down into HTML files. The end goal would be to code a (pretty much static) website in PHP and deploy it as HTML files.

Comment: The fact that your site is built in PHP is probably not material to the question. What you want to do is just save the whole site as it appears to visitors. I believe there's any number of pre-built tools out there that will do this.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I did actually try finding one before asking this, but found nothing. If you got any recommendations for such software, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) or Symfony's [panther](https://github.com/symfony/panther)?

Comment: One of them, I'll check out panther.

Comment: Scraping is really easy and straightforward. The major problem is that you'll need to rewrite the HTML to match your new links. So anything that pointed to `/about-us` will need to be rewritten to `/about-us.html` in the reference pages. Assets not loaded directly in HTML, such as things coming from CSS or JS, get much harder without an actual renderer. You'll also want to safe-list your domain(s) for 1st/3rd party, and decide how you want to handle the latter.

Comment: Re: _"So anything that pointed to `/about-us` will need to be rewritten to `/about-us.html`"_ @ChrisHaas is right, but it's also worth mentioning (for those relatively unfamiliar with urls) that if a page `/about-us/index.php` is updated to `/about-us/index.html`, then an `href="/about-us/"` link to the old PHP page will continue to link to the new HTML page.

Comment: Could output buffer functions help?

Comment: Alrighty, I a friend of mine made me a little script that does it. Still thanks everyone tho!